# Text not showing on canvas in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text

I am trying to display text on the screen and it's not working for me.

Here is some of my code you give you an idea on what I made:

duck.js

```
class duck {
  constructor (canvas, logs = false, start = () => {}, update = () => {}) {
    document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden';

    self.canvas = canvas;
    self.ctx = self.canvas.getContext('2d');
    self.logs = logs;

    self.keys = {};
    window.onkeyup = (e) => self.keys[e.keyCode] = false;

    var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
    var style_height = +getComputedStyle(self.canvas).getPropertyValue("height").slice(0, -2);
    var style_width = +getComputedStyle(self.canvas).getPropertyValue("width").slice(0, -2);
    self.canvas.setAttribute('height', style_height * dpi);
    self.canvas.setAttribute('width', style_width * dpi);

    self.init = () => {
        var a;

        self.logs ? console.info('Duck initialized!') : a = 0;
    };

    self.init.call();

    start();
    setInterval(update, 1);
  };

  rect (x = 0, y = 0, w = 1, h = 1, color = "#FFFFFF", fill = true) {
    self.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    fill ? self.ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h): self.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  fill (color = "#000000") {
    self.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    self.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  text (x = 0, y = 0, text = 'Hello world!', align='left', font = '16px Verdana', color = '#000000') {
    self.ctx.font = font;
    console.log(self.ctx.font)
    self.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    console.log(self.ctx.fillStyle);
    self.ctx.textAlign = align;
    console.log(self.ctx.textAlign)
    self.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
  }

  get getWidth() {
    return canvas.width;
  }

  get getHeight() {
    return canvas.height;
  }

  screenshot() {
    var image = self.canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    window.location.href = image;
  }

  keyDown(key = 'q') {
    if (self.keys[key]) {return true} else {return false};
  }
}
```

index.js

```
let duck_core = new duck(document.getElementById('main'), true, start, update);

function start() {
  console.log('test');
}

function update() {
  duck_core.fill('#FFFFFF');
  duck_core.rect(0, 0, duck_core.getWidth, 10, '#222222');
  duck_core.text(0, 0);

  if (duck_core.keyDown('q')) {
    duck_core.screenshot();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look into the console. Your `text` function (I assume it should be a function) misses the `function` keyword. Besides that, please provide more code or, even better, create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: text is in a class and selfctx is the 2d context of the canvas

Comment: Again: Please add _all_ relevant parts of your code to the question. How should people on SO know that `text` is part of a class?

Comment: @David added full code

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it wasn't showing is that the text has the center point on the bottom left corner and not the top right corner. To fix this, I added t the y position the size of my text, in this case, 16px.

Answer (score 0):

Change `self` to `this` inside your `duck` class. In JavaScript, the global `self` variable is a reference to the `window` object, meaning it doesn't point to the instance of your class:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)

**EDIT**

You also have to update these parts:

```
get getWidth() {
    return this.canvas.width; // added "this"
}

get getHeight() {
    return this.canvas.height; // added "this"
}
```